# Xcode throws error while taking build archive for release"could not find included file '../plugins-release.xcconfig' in search paths (in target )"

Tags: xcode, nativescript

After generating a web pack build using this command:

```
npm run build-ios-bundle.
```

We have created an Xcode workspace for the application.
When I take archive from Xcode we got runtime error. Here I'm unable to take the build archive for app submission into Appstore release.

Comment: Please elaborate about what you are trying to do and the specific error you've received.

Comment: Please, provide more details about the error you are receiving. Also, what the "build-ios-bundle" npm script stands for?